# CQ5.5: getting Style of a target page

Tags: aem

I've been working on this for sometime now, and I keep running into a wall. I think I'm close, but I figured someone out here in the land of SO might have some deeper insight if not a better way of doing what I'm trying to do.

Basically lets look at this scenario. I have a logo w/ some text that can be set from a few different places. If we look at the setup here is what it looks like.

```
Hiearchy:
Homepage [has designPath]
  - Child Microsite Page [has designPath]
    - Logo Component

Logic Flow (in logo component):
if properties.get("logoText") {
  use this
} else if currentStyle.get("logoTextFromStyle") {
  use this
} else if parentStyle.get("logoTextFromGlobal") {
  use this
} else {
  be blank
}
```

My query is with how to get the "parentStyle" of this page. Looking at the docs here: http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/designer/Style.html

I've been able to come up with the fact that I can get a Style object from the "designer" object made available via defineObjects. This is defined with the other utility objects like "pageManager, resourceUtil, resource, currentPage, etc".

With that being said this doesn't seem to work.

```
//assuming we have getting homePage earlier and it is a valid cq Page resource
Resource homePageResource.slingRequest.getResourceResolver().getResource(homePage.getPath());
Style homePageStyle = designer.getStyle(homePageResource);
```

at this point homePageStyle is null. To do some more testing I i tried passing currentPage.getPath() instead of homePage.getPath().  I assumed this would give me the currentPage resource and would in end yield the currentStyle object. This also resulted in a null Style object. From this I think I can safely conclude I'm passing the incorrect resource type.

I attempted to load the the cq:designPath into the resource hoping to get a Designer resourceType but to no avail.

I am curious if anyone has run into this problem before. I apologize if I've gone into too much detail, but I wanted to lay out the "why" to my question as well, just in case there was a better way overall of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out how to return the style.  Here is the rundown of what I did.

```
//get your page object
Page targetPage = pageManager.getPage("/path/to/target");

//get the Design object of the target page
Design homePageDesign = designer.getDesign(homePage);

//extract the style from the design using the design path
Style homePageStyle = homePageDesign.getStyle(homePageDesign.getPath());
```

it's very interesting the definition of "getStyle" is a little different from the designer.getStyle vs a Design.getStyle. designer.getStyle asks for a resource whereas Design.getStyle will take the path to a Design "cell" and return the appropriate Style.

I did some testing and it looks like it does work with inherited Styles/Designs. So if my cq:designPath is set at level 1 and I look up a page on at level 2 they will return the Design/Style at the cq:designPath set at level 1.

I hope this helps someone else down the way.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this approach but was not getting the Styles in the Style object.
When we do this:

Design `homePageDesign` = `designer.getDesign(homePage);`

In this Design object we get the path till the project node i.e etc/design/myproject

After this if we try to extract the Style from the design path we do not get it.

However I implemented it in a different way.

1. In the design object, we also get the complete JSON of designs for(etc/design/myproject).
2. Get the sling:resourceType of the target page and get the  value after last index of "/".
3. Check if this JSON contains the last value. If it contains, you can get your styles, i.e. image, etc.